# Download public URL in Downloads folder in Flutter web

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter web app integrated with firebase.
By pressing a button, I am able to open in a new tab a public URL file that is stored in Google Cloud storage through the command: launchUrl(Uri.parse(gcs_url)); What I would like instead is to download the file to the local Downloads folder. Sorry I am a flutter beginner and despite this being a basic task, I am having a lot of problems. Note that this is a web application. The command should work on Windows, iOS, and Linux.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
Future<void> downloadFile(String url, String fileName) async {

  final anchor = AnchorElement(href: url);

  anchor.setAttribute('download', fileName);
 
  await anchor.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio/install) package to download file.

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

final dio = Dio();
var pathToSave= "/WHERE YOU WANTED TO BE"
response = await dio.download(gcs_url,pathToSave);
```

**Note:** you might need permission to store a file, depends on where you save and in which device your are using